# How many icons i can place in iphone tool bar? is there any limit?

Tags: numbers, icons, toolbar

How many icons i can place in iphone tool bar? is there any limit? Can we add more than 5 like 6 or 7

Answer (score 2):

no there is no limit but it will create problem if you put icons very close

Maintain a hit target area of at `least 44 x 44 points` for each toolbar item. If you crowd toolbar items too closely together, people have difficulty tapping the one they want.

so in your case it will be problematic while tapping the icon on UIToolBar because the icon will be very close to one another

please read this guidelines at developer.apple.com [Icons for Toolbars](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW8)
if you want to give even space for the buttons in toolbar then put flexiblespace button after each button

Create a `UIBarButtonItem` with the `-initWithBarButtonSystemItem:` method using `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace`, and insert that between each of your actual toolbar items.

E.g.:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *FlexiButton = [[UIBarButton alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace];
 myToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:buttonOne,FlexiButton,buttonTwo,FlexiButton,buttonThree,nil];
[FlexiButton release];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bhavak, the information provided is helpful

Comment: hmm..enjoye the coding and ma name is bhavik..hehe...anyways..if its solve your problem then please mark as answer

Comment: How much space should be be left in between toolbar button

Comment: please see my upadated answer for spacing evenly in between all button of toolbar